# Widget flickers and disappears when scrolling

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm already losing sleep over this.

I'm trying to display a chart inside a `ListView` (for scrolling). For some reason the contents of the `Card` flickers when scrolling and randomly completely disappears (the `Card` itself stays visible though).

Any idea why would that happen?

```
(...) ListView (...)
children: [Row ( children: [buildChartBox()] )] (...)


Expanded buildChartBox() {
   return Expanded(
     child: Card(
       child: Padding(
         padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
         child: Column(
           children: [
             Column(
               mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
               children: [
                 chartTitles(
                     title: 'Items',
                     subtitle: 'by value'),
                 SizedBox(
                     height: 300,
                     child: ValuesChart(data: calculateValues(items)))
               ],
             ),
           ],
         ),
       ),
     ),
   );
 }




Row chartTitles({String title = '', String subtitle = ''}) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text(title, style: text_charttitle),
            Text(subtitle, style: text_chartsubtitle),
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

Things tried:

- Both of these were originally Stateless Widgets; I changed to simple
  methods to simplify but it didn't change the weird behaviour.
- Replacing the `chartTitles` `return` with an empty `Container` (i.e. removing the titles) does mitigate the issue. The chart then stays displayed but also flickers *slightly*.
- Replacing the `ListView` with a `SingleChildScrollView` doesn't change anything.

EDIT: Code for the ValuesChart:

```
import 'package:fl_chart/fl_chart.dart';

class ValuesChart extends StatelessWidget {
  final Map<String, int> data;

  const ValuesChart({required this.data});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: PieChart(
      _theData(data),
    ));
  }
}
```

Note I'm using a package called 'fl_chart'. `_theData` just returns various parameters for the chart, I don't think it's relevant.

Comment: can you share your ValuesChart codes? if u replace that with a simple text widget does the issue presisit?

Comment: I added the code for ValuesChart. Yes, in fact replacing the chart with a simple Text widget doesn't do this. 

I also tried keeping the chart in a StateFUL widget in case it's losing data when rebuilt during scrolling or something - still the same effect.

Comment: If thats the case maybe it has something to do with the PieChart widget. Maybe look it up with the package developer?

Comment: It would seem so. What's weird though is that the entire content of the card disappears randomly -- along with the titles which are not really connected to the PieChart. Anyway thanks for looking at this - I'll dig some more in the 'issues' section on Github for this package.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `ListView` with `SingleChildScrollView`

`ListView`s in flutter by default using what it is called in Android `RecyclerView` to efficiently use render resources.
If you are interested here an article
https://medium.com/1mgofficial/how-recyclerview-works-internally-71290de5d2c4

Comment: Good shot  - unfortunately with a SingleChildScrollView the problem persists. Interesting article though!